# How do you show a list of site owners for a SharePoint site, using a WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi newbie here but wish to know how I list all Site Owners for a site on a Site Page?

Comment: There is no SharePoint out of the box web part available for this. You will have to develop custom web part using SPFx.

Comment: Yes, you need to develop custom SPFx web part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the People web part and manually list the site owners, though the displayed users (site owners) would need to be maintained by someone manually. The other option would be to create a SPFx web part which can dynamically list the site owners for the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ‘Site Users’ WebPart.

Edit the page and add the ‘Site Users’ WebPart.
From the small arrow drop-down, click 'Edit Web Part'.
Under ‘Site Users’, click the ‘Show People in this Group’ radio button.
Enter the name of the site owner group.

Or use the following webpart code snippet:

[How do you show a list of site owners for a SharePoint site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104570/how-do-you-show-a-list-of-site-owners-for-a-sharepoint-site)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/site-groups/web";
import "@pnp/sp/site-users/web";

export interface IOwnersProps {
}

export interface IOwnersState {
    owners: string[];
}

export default class Owners extends React.Component<IOwnersProps, IOwnersState> {
    constructor(props: IOwnersProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            owners: []
        };
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        this._getOwners();
    }

    private _getOwners(): void {
        sp.web.associatedOwnerGroup.users.get().then(users => {
            const owners = users.map(user => user.Title);
            this.setState({ owners });
        });
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IOwnersProps> {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Site Owners</h2>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.owners.map(owner => <li key={owner}>{owner}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet is not feasible in SharePoint Online, as it refers to a solution that must be deployed to the farm and is written in C#

Comment: Hi Callum thanks for pointing that out, ive adjusted the answer for the webpart code.